# Printing two dimensional array in table format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created array of movies object and other array of genres for the movies. Now I want to use loop to print data into table. Array of genres should be table heading and array of movies should be table data. I am trying to print two dimensional array into table in my javascript program but I am getting different output. I used table tag and accordingly all tags which requires to print data in table.But not getting output as requires.Could anyone please help me? Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Lab 7 </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <h1 style="font-family: monospace;  text-align: center; 
    text-shadow: 
    1.5em .4em 10vw orange, 
    0 0 10vw gold;
    font-size: 3vw;"> Movies Inventory </h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function movie(the_title, the_rating, the_price) {
            this.title = the_title;
            this.rating = the_rating;
            this.price = the_price;
            this.display = displayClass;
        }

        function displayClass() {
            document.write("<span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Title : </span>", this.title + "<br>");
            document.write("<span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Rating : </span>", this.rating + "<br>");
            document.write("<span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Price : </span>", this.price + "<br>");
            document.write('<br />');
        }


 var myMovie = new movie("Minions", "PG", '$' + 11.49);   
 var myMovie2 = new movie("Terminator Genisys", 'PG - '+ 13, '$' + 11.99);  
 var myMovie3 = new movie( "Taken 2", 'PG - '+ 13, '$' + 12.99);

 var myMovie4 = new movie("Ted 2", "R", '$' + 13.49);
 var myMovie5 = new movie ("Jurassic World", 'PG - '+ 13, '$' + 12.49);
 var myMovie6 = new movie("True Story", "R", '$' + 12.99);

 var myMovie7 = new movie("The Intern", 'PG -' + 13, '$' + 12.49);
 var myMovie8 = new movie("Edge of Tomorrow", 'PG -' + 13, '$' + 12.99 );
 var myMovie9 = new movie("Concussion", 'PG -' + 13, '$' + 13.49 );

  genre = new Array("Comedy", "Science Fiction", "Drama");
  movie = new Array(myMovie, myMovie2, myMovie3);
  movie2 = new Array(myMovie4, myMovie5, myMovie6);
  movie3 = new Array(myMovie7, myMovie8, myMovie9); 


        document.write("<span style ='text-align: center; font-size: 160%; font-family:monospace'>   Number of genres in the inventory: </span> " + genre.length);  document.write('<br />'); document.write('<br />'); document.write('<br />');
    </script>


body{

background-image: url(lab7_images/back.jpg);
height: 100%;
/*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
background-size: cover;
text-align: center;
font-family: Courier, monospace;
   }

html.js  {

font-size: 120%;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
border-style: double;

 }

span{

color: #000;
font-size: 120%;
font-family: Courier, monospace;

}

   </style>
   </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    </script>

</table>
```

```
output:
```

After changing code output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title> Lab 7 </title>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <h1 style="font-family: monospace;  text-align: center; 
    text-shadow: 
    1.5em .4em 10vw orange, 
    0 0 10vw gold;
    font-size: 3vw;"> Movies Inventory </h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    function movie(the_title, the_rating, the_price) {
    this.title = the_title;
    this.rating = the_rating;
    this.price = the_price;     
    this.display = displayClass;
}

    function displayClass(){
    document.write("<span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Title : </span>", this.title + "<br>");
    document.write("<span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Rating : </span>", this.rating + "<br>");
    document.write("<span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Price : </span>", this.price + "<br>");
    document.write('<br />');
}


    var myMovie = new movie("Minions", "PG", '$' + 11.49);   
    var myMovie2 = new movie("Terminator Genisys", 'PG - '+ 13, '$' + 11.99);  
    var myMovie3 = new movie( "Taken 2", 'PG - '+ 13, '$' + 12.99);

    var myMovie4 = new movie("Ted 2", "R", '$' + 13.49);
    var myMovie5 = new movie ("Jurassic World", 'PG - '+ 13, '$' + 12.49);
    var myMovie6 = new movie("True Story", "R", '$' + 12.99);

    var myMovie7 = new movie("The Intern", 'PG -' + 13, '$' + 12.49);
    var myMovie8 = new movie("Edge of Tomorrow", 'PG -' + 13, '$' + 12.99 );
    var myMovie9 = new movie("Concussion", 'PG -' + 13, '$' + 13.49 );


    genre = new Array("Comedy", "Science Fiction", "Drama");
    movie = new Array(myMovie, myMovie2, myMovie3);
    movie2 = new Array(myMovie4, myMovie5, myMovie6);
    movie3 = new Array(myMovie7, myMovie8, myMovie9);
    images = new Array("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/25/21/d6/2521d66145c91e8e49e20b9649e7d4a7.jpg", "image_2_url", "image_3_url");
    images2 = new Array("image_4_url", "image_5_url", "image_6_url");
    images3 = new Array("image_7_url", "image_8_url", "image_9_url");

   </script>

   </head>
   <body>

    <table border="2", align="center">
      <tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
              document.write('<th>'+genre[i]+'</th>') }
        </script>
      </tr>        

      <tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          document.write("<td>")
          movie[j].display();
          document.write("<img src='")
          document.write(images[j])
          document.write(" '")
          document.write(" width='200' height='200' ")
          document.write(" > ")
          document.write("</td>")} 
        </script>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          document.write("<td>")
          movie2[j].display();
          document.write("<img src='")
          document.write(images2[j])
          document.write(" '")
          document.write(" width='200' height='200' ")
          document.write(" > ")
          document.write("</td>")} 
        </script>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <script type="text/javascript">for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
          document.write("<td>")
          movie3[j].display();
          document.write("<img src='")
          document.write(images3[j])
          document.write(" '")
          document.write(" width='200' height='200' ")
          document.write(" > ")
          document.write("</td>")} 
        </script>
      </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: How can I put three different movie images below all three movies ?

Comment: You can create one more row, and save the images url same as genre.and you can use  <img> tag. I Will code it in few hours going to sleep, until u can try.

Comment: sure I will try. but you also put your response i code here....Thank you.

Comment: I want to put image in same cell description is...exactly below description.

Comment: I have updated my code, check it out. you can paste your images url in images array, and you can also change the resolution of images in code.

Comment: Thank you so much...you saved my day.

Comment: Welcome, hope this is exactly what you were looking for.BTW it was my first answer on stack overflow :)

Comment: Yeah it's exactly what I want. But How to display all images in center in cell ? like I displayed terminator movie image in center ? Please see my updated code above

Comment: you can use cell padding `<table border="4", align="center" cellpadding="20" >` just update the table tag line, use padding as much as u need.

Comment: if you want you can also add cell spacing `cellspacing="5"` it will look good.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155131/discussion-between-pooja-gajera-and-mukul-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider change this line

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    document.write("<td>");
    document.write(movie[j].display());
    document.write("</td>");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks james, But after changes I am not getting desirable output. What else changes do I need to make ?

Comment: @poojagajera You might consider add some html element tagging around the display

Answer (score 1):

**Edit using javascript template [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with images added to the movie object and removed displayClass function and changed out the hard coded 3 with movie.length and genre.length**

I think you want something like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

   function movie(the_title, the_rating, the_price, img_path) {
    this.title = the_title;
    this.rating = the_rating;
    this.price = the_price;
    this.img = img_path;
   }

   var myMovie = new movie("Minions", "PG", '$' + 11.49,"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTg2MTMyMzU0M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTU3ODk4NTE@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg");
   var myMovie2 = new movie("Terminator Genisys", 'PG - '+ 13, '$' + 11.99,"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjM1NTc0NzE4OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDkyNjQ1NTE@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg");
   var myMovie3 = new movie( "Taken 2", 'PG - '+ 13, '$' + 12.99,"https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTkwNTQ0ODExOV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjU3NDQwOA@@._V1_UX182_CR0,0,182,268_AL_.jpg");

   genre = new Array("Comedy", "Science Fiction", "Drama");
   movie = new Array(myMovie, myMovie2, myMovie3);

  </script>

  <body>
  </head>
  <table border="2", align="center">
      <thead>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  let tableHead = "";
  let tableBody = "";
  for (i = 0; i < genre.length; i++) {
    tableHead +=`<th> ${genre[i]} </th> `
  };
  tableHead += `</thead>`
  tableBody = `<tbody><tr>`
  for (j = 0; j < movie.length; j++) {
   tableBody +=
   `<td><span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Title : </span>${movie[j].title}<br>
          <span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Rating : </span>${movie[j].rating}<br>
          <span style='color:black; font-size: 120%'> Price : </span>${movie[j].price}<br>
          <img src="${movie[j].img}">
    </td>`
  };
 tableBody += `</tr></tbody></table>`
 document.write(tableHead + tableBody);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But how to separate heading? All heading are showing in one cell. Please look at my updated output above

Comment: How can I put three different movie images below all three movies ?

Comment: I would do this differently for an actual database application, but as far as practice with objects and strings it works.

Comment: I tried your method to display images but it doesn't work Plus I also added my methods it doesn't seems to work also. Could you please look at updated code above ?

Comment: your movie object needs to take in a parameter for the image path, then you need to add a write line to the display function like this:
document.write("<img src='" + this.img + "'>");